# XSLT. convert number to Indian format

Tags: xslt

While using number format in XSLT:

Input is: **135678.00**

Expected output : **1,35,678.00**

The output which I got is: **135,678.00**

Could someone please help me out?

```
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="format-number(135678.00,'##,##,###.00')"/>
```

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? Is it an XSLT 1.0 processor, or XSLT 2.0 or above?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(135678.00, '#,##,##,###.00')"/>
```

Comment: Refer here: http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB32

Comment: still it remains the same

Comment: @AmrendraKumar Refer here: http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB32/1

Comment: @michael.hor257k why its happen some times?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 vs. XSLT 2.0.